# python: Create a multiindex pandas DF based on condition of column names

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
arrays = [np.array(["berlin", "berlin", "paris", "paris", "rome", "rome", "seville", "seville"]),
          np.array(["one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two"])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays, columns = ['mike','ana','manu','analia'])
```

it has a multiindex in the rows.
I would like to transform that DF into another one that would also have a multindex in the columns.

the function could be generalized as this:

```
def sortit(colname):
    if colname.startswith('m'):
        return 'm'
    elif colname.startswith('m'): 
        return 'a'
```

The expected output is the following:

```
arrays = [np.array(["berlin", "berlin", "paris", "paris", "rome", "rome", "seville", "seville"]),
          np.array(["one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two"])]
tuples_i = list(zip(*arrays))
index_rows = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples_i, names=["city", "number"])
arrays2 = [np.array(["m","m", "a","a"]),
          np.array(['mike','manu','ana','analia'])]
tuples_c = list(zip(*arrays2))
print(tuples)
index_columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples_c, names=["department", "name"])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=index_rows, columns = index_columns)

df
```

two important notes.

My starting point is the dataframe with multindex in the rows and no multiindex in the cols. I can not change that.

The method that illustrates here to which multiindex belong every name (column name) is a straight forward one, as example, the reality is that that function is way more complicated and time consuming, that's why I would like to create once the multilevel col index to make queries later much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

you can make multi index easily from making tuple

```
(df.set_axis(df.columns.map(lambda x: (x[0], x)), axis=1)
 .rename_axis(['department', 'name'], axis=1))
```

output:

```
department  m       a       m       a
name        mike    ana     manu    analia
berlin  one 0.6     -0.0    2.9     1.3
        two 1.3     0.4     0.0     -3.0
paris   one -0.5    -0.8    0.4     0.0
        two -0.6    -1.0    0.5     0.3
rome    one -1.5    0.2     -0.0    1.4
        two -1.5    -1.9    0.0     -0.0
seville one -1.3    1.3     0.7     0.5
        two -0.2    -0.2    -0.7    0.4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can craft a new MultiIndex with [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns.str.extract('(.)', expand=False),
                                 df.columns],
                                names=['department', 'name'])

df.columns = idx

print(df.sort_index(level=0, axis=1))
```

Output:

```
department          a                   m          
name              ana    analia      manu      mike
berlin  one  0.465270 -0.549246  0.931020  0.027496
        two -2.156006 -2.053703  0.162281  0.741966
paris   one  0.084072  1.729949  1.366554  0.402933
        two  1.157244  1.762093 -1.808943 -1.737110
rome    one -0.009257 -0.457297 -0.479836 -2.483149
        two -0.593379 -0.012763 -1.491018 -0.439712
seville one -1.118433  0.029189 -0.805858 -0.342481
        two -0.389120 -0.390189 -1.260496 -0.010572
```